# PyTorch: running Neural Network in identical venv-configuration - one working fine, one keeps throwing 'list index out of range' error

Tags: python, pytorch, jupyter-lab, pytorch-dataloader

I set up an virtual environment via 'venv' to build and train a neural network using PyTorch and JupyterLab. However, when working on my computer 'PC 1' everything works fine, but running the same code with identical Python settings on my second computer ('PC 2') keeps constantly an error ('list index out of range') thrown while training.
Any suggestions what might cause this behavior? I'm running out of ideas ...

To be more specific:

- On both computers Python 3.7.9 is installed via the Microsoft Store.
- To be clear: both computers access the same *.ipynb and the same data / datasets, which are synced via a cloud service.

I tried:

- I synced the created venv (via a cloud), activated venv and runned the *.ipynb via jupyter-lab (on 'PC 2') -> error
- I got my venv-configuration from the working 'PC 1' via  `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and set up a fresh venv on 'PC 2' using the `requirements.txt`-> error

Nevertheless I try, the thrown error is always the same.

This is the error thrown:
('julab' is my venv)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9608\2329219183.py in <module>
     10     val_dl = test_loader,
     11     epochs=num_epochs,
---> 12     device='cpu')

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9608\132402798.py in train(model, optimizer, loss_fn, train_dl, val_dl, epochs, device)
     27         num_train_examples = 0
     28 
---> 29         for batch in train_dl:
     30 
     31             optimizer.zero_grad()

d:\<CLOUD>\<SUBFOLDER>\julab\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    650                 # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    651                 self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 652             data = self._next_data()
    653             self._num_yielded += 1
    654             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

d:\<CLOUD>\<SUBFOLDER>\julab\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    690     def _next_data(self):
    691         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 692         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    693         if self._pin_memory:
    694             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

d:\<CLOUD>\<SUBFOLDER>\julab\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     47     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     48         if self.auto_collation:
---> 49             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     50         else:
     51             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

d:\<CLOUD>\<SUBFOLDER>\julab\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     47     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     48         if self.auto_collation:
---> 49             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     50         else:
     51             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

d:\<CLOUD>\<SUBFOLDER>\julab\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataset.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
    288         if isinstance(idx, list):
    289             return self.dataset[[self.indices[i] for i in idx]]
--> 290         return self.dataset[self.indices[idx]]
    291 
    292     def __len__(self):

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9608\2122586536.py in __getitem__(self, index)
     32 
     33     def __getitem__(self, index):
---> 34         image_name = os.path.join(self.image_dir, self.image_files[index])
     35         image = PIL.Image.open(image_name)
     36         label = self.data[index]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

And as this might help, this is my `requirements.txt`:

```
anyio==3.6.1
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
attrs==21.4.0
Babel==2.10.3
backcall==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
bleach==5.0.1
certifi==2022.6.15
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.0
colorama==0.4.5
cycler==0.11.0
debugpy==1.6.0
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
dill==0.3.5.1
entrypoints==0.4
fastjsonschema==2.15.3
fonttools==4.33.3
idna==3.3
importlib-metadata==4.12.0
importlib-resources==5.8.0
ipykernel==6.15.0
ipython==7.34.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jedi==0.18.1
Jinja2==3.1.2
joblib==1.1.0
json5==0.9.8
jsonschema==4.6.1
jupyter-client==7.3.4
jupyter-core==4.10.0
jupyter-server==1.18.0
jupyterlab==3.4.3
jupyterlab-pygments==0.2.2
jupyterlab-server==2.14.0
kiwisolver==1.4.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
matplotlib==3.5.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
mistune==0.8.4
nbclassic==0.4.0
nbclient==0.6.6
nbconvert==6.5.0
nbformat==5.4.0
nest-asyncio==1.5.5
notebook-shim==0.1.0
numpy==1.21.6
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.3.5
pandocfilters==1.5.0
parso==0.8.3
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==9.2.0
prometheus-client==0.14.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.30
psutil==5.9.1
pycparser==2.21
Pygments==2.12.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyrsistent==0.18.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.1
pywin32==304
pywinpty==2.0.5
pyzmq==23.2.0
requests==2.28.1
scikit-learn==1.0.2
scipy==1.7.3
Send2Trash==1.8.0
six==1.16.0
sklearn==0.0
sniffio==1.2.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
terminado==0.15.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
tinycss2==1.1.1
torch==1.12.0
torchsummary==1.5.1
torchvision==0.13.0
tornado==6.1
traitlets==5.3.0
typing_extensions==4.3.0
urllib3==1.26.9
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.3.3
zipp==3.8.0
```

Has anyone an idea what's the problem and how to solve it? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to make sure- have you tried running the code that generates the dataset using PC2?

Comment: @Tamir: yes, the dataset is successfully load from my disk and I can visualize a random subset of the images.

Comment: Can you please attach the output of `len(dataset)` for each one of your environments?

Comment: Yes, of course: *PC1: `print(len(dset))` => 440 *PC2:  `print(len(dset))` => 440

Comment: Can you also attach the `len` of `self.image_files` (from the DS)  from each one of them?

Comment: Ah, here seems to be the problem, thank you @Tamir! For PC1 I got: `len(self.image_files):  440`, for PC2 it's: `len(self.image_files):  436`. I then checked the folder with the image data, and somehow it seems to be an issue with synching the data via cloud, as there are actually 4 images missing in the folder of PC2 - although the cloud-service states 'all fine!'. The same folder on PC1 has all images. However, adding the missing files manually and re-synching solved my problem - my NN is working now on both machines! :-) Thanks, @Tamir for guiding me on the right way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[solved] see comments above...